# Where to specify the driver version db h2?

Tags: spring, h2

there are two databases h2 of different versions: 1.4.200 and 2.1.214.

contents of the application.yaml file:

```
app:
  datasource1:
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:~/database/test1
    driverClassname: org.h2.Driver
    h2.version: 1.4.200
    username: xxx
    password: xxx

  datasource2:
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:~/database/test2
    driverClassname: org.h2.Driver
    h2.version: 2.1.214
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
```

there are two configuration classes: DataSourcesConfiguration1 и DataSourcesConfiguration2.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DataSourcesConfiguration1 {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.datasource1")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties1() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean("dataSource1")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.datasource1")
    public HikariDataSource dataSource1() {
        return dataSourceProperties1()
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean("jdbcTemplate1")
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1()
    {
        HikariDataSource ds = dataSource1();
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("transactionManager1")
    DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager1() {
        HikariDataSource ds = dataSource1();
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(ds);
    }
}
```

the DataSourcesConfiguration2 class looks similar, without the @Primary annotation.

I do not know where to specify the db driver version.
I can only specify the version in the file pom.xml, but it works for two data sources:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
<!-- <version>2.1.214</version> -->
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

lines
h2.version: 1.4.200 and h2.version: 2.1.214
specified in the file application.yaml, ignored when creating beans.
need to find some property HikariDataSource ds.setDriverVersion();

but I don't know where to specify the driver version db h2 ?

Comment: You don't as that isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load two versions of H2 at once, unless they are loaded by different classloaders.

H2 1.4.200 is an old unsupported version, why you need to use it these days? If you want to move your data from old version of H2 to new one you can try to use `org.h2.tools.Upgrade` class in H2 2.1.214 or you can use a third-party upgrade tool: https://github.com/manticore-projects/H2MigrationTool

But if you really need to use them both, the simplest solution is to include H2 2.1.214 to the classpath of your application and start a separate H2 Server process with H2 1.4.200 (`java -jar h2-1.4.200.jar`), connection URLs will be `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/database/test1` for 1.4.200 and the same `jdbc:h2:~/database/test2` for 2.1.214.

Your application will use a remote database on 1.4.200 server and embedded database opened by 2.1.214.

Comment: Which would still require 2 drivers on the class path to support the remote server. I doubt that with an H2 v2 driver you can connect to a H2 v1 server and vice/versa.

Comment: No, you need H2 1.4.200 in classpath of another Java process with TCP server of H2. You don't need it in classpath of your main application. Client driver included into 2.1.214 can connect to servers with H2 1.4.197 and newer versions.

Comment: Evgenij Ryazanov, I'll try.